# Releasing Shared Memory

Tags: c, process, shared-memory

So the program below accesses a piece of shared memory at location "shmid" and attaches it to pointer "total." A child process is then created that accesses and modifies this piece of memory and then once complete, another child process is created and does the same, and then a 3rd child. Once these 3 children have finished modifying the value and finished executing, the parent process releases the shared memory and then the program exits. I was under the impression that this "shmctl" block would have the desired effect, but it doesn't seem to.

```
if ((shmctl (shmid, IPC_RMID, (struct shmid_ds *) 0)) == -1)
{
  perror ("shmctl");
 exit (-1);
}
```

I don't believe it does, because following this block I have the following which during execution printed out the same value as before. Doesn't this indicate that the pointer is still accessing the same bit of memory, or am I mistaken?

```
printf("value after memory release:%d\n", total->value);
```

Thank you for your input!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* change the key number */
#define SHMKEY ((key_t) 5600) //7890

typedef struct
{
  int value;
} shared_mem;

shared_mem *total;

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
 * This function increases the value of shared variable "total"
 *  by one all the way to 100000
 *----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

void process1 ()
{
  int k = 0;

  while (k < 100000)
  {
      k++;
      total->value = total->value + 1;
  }
  printf ("From process1 total = %d\n", total->value); //process 1 prints out total and  returns to main() function
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
 * This function increases the vlaue of shared memory variable "total"
 *  by one all the way to 170000
 *----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

void process2 ()
{
  int k = 0;

  while (k < 170000)
  {
  k++;
  total->value = total->value + 1;
  }
  printf ("From process2 total = %d\n", total->value); //process 2 prints out total and returns to main() function
}
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
 * This function increases the vlaue of shared memory variable "total"
 *  by one all the way to 200000
 *----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

void process3 ()
{
  int k = 0;

  while (k < 200000)
  {
    k++;
    total->value = total->value + 1;
  }
  printf ("From process3 total = %d\n", total->value); //process 3 prints out total and returns to main() function
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
 * MAIN()
 *----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

int main()
{
  int shmid;
  int pid1;
  int pid2;
  int pid3;
  int ID;
  int status;

  char *shmadd;
  shmadd = (char *) 0;

/* Create and connect to a shared memory segmentt*/

if ((shmid = shmget (SHMKEY, sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT | 0666)) < 0)
{
  perror ("shmget");
  exit (1);
}


if ((total = (shared_mem *) shmat (shmid, shmadd, 0)) == (shared_mem *) -1)
{
  perror ("shmat");
  exit (0);
}

total->value = 0;

if ((pid1 = fork()) == 0) //first child created
{
  process1(); //first child process begins
}

while((ID = wait(&status)) != -1) //parent loops until 1st child is finished
printf("child %d is finished\n", ID); //parent prints out returned value after child is finished


if ((pid1 != 0) && ((pid2 = fork()) == 0)) //second child created
{
  process2(); //second child process begins
}   

while((ID = wait(&status)) != -1) //parent loops until 2nd child is finished
printf("child %d is finished\n", ID); //parent prints out returned value after child is finished

if ((pid1 != 0) && (pid2 != 0) && ((pid3 = fork()) == 0)) //third child created
{
  process3(); //third child process begins
}

while((ID = wait(&status)) != -1) //parent loops until 3rd child is finished
printf("child %d is finished\n", ID); //parent prints out returned value after child is finished



if ((pid1 != 0) && (pid2 != 0) && (pid3 != 0)) 
{
  if ((shmctl (shmid, IPC_RMID, (struct shmid_ds *) 0)) == -1)
  {
 perror ("shmctl");
 exit (-1);
  }

  printf ("\t\t  End of Program.\n"); //prints after all children have finished

  printf("value after memory release:%d\n", total->value);
}
return 0;
} 

/***** Note:  loop for parent to wait for child processes to finish and print ID of each child*****/
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be tagged with C++? C would have been more relevant?

Comment: My bad. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the shmctl man page:

> IPC_RMID
>
> Mark the segment to be destroyed. The segment will only actually be
>   destroyed after the last process detaches it (i.e., when the
>   shm_nattch member of the associated structure shmid_ds is zero). The
>   caller must be the owner or creator, or be privileged. If a segment
>   has been marked for destruction, then the (nonstandard) SHM_DEST flag
>   of the shm_perm.mode field in the associated data structure retrieved
>   by IPC_STAT will be set.
>
> The caller must ensure that a segment is eventually destroyed;
>   otherwise its pages that were faulted in will remain in memory or
>   swap.

i.e. your code marks the segment for destruction, but does not detach it until program exit.

If you want to detach it earlier, you can call `shmdt(total);`. If you do this before that last printf, the printf is likely to cause a seg fault.